# Why does Hebrew transcribe Akkadian š inconsistently?

Tags: historical-linguistics, borrowing, transcription, hebrew, semitic-languages

Biblical Hebrew consistently uses the letter ס (s) to transcribe names with the Akkadian consonant š. For example, [Esarhaddon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esarhaddon) for Aššur-aḥa-iddina, [Esther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esther#Origin_and_meaning_of_the_name_Esther) from Ištar, [Sargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargon_II) from Šarru-ukīn (all Akkadian transcriptions copied from Wikipedia). Etymologically, Akkadian š and Hebrew š almost always correspond (š and ṯ, although Akkadian š can also correspond to Hebrew ś, but not to s to my knowledge).

The only exception I can think of is Aššur which is transcribed that way (with š). Since the Aramaic reflex is Attur, the word seems to have reached both languages as a descendant (through *Aṯṯur) and not a borrowing.

On the other hand, [Shalmaneser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalmaneser_V) comes from Šulmanu-ašarid, and yet preserves the š at the beginning of the word, while the second š is transcribed as s.

My question is: Why does Hebrew not transcribe Akkadian š with Hebrew ש (š) instead of ס (s)? Does this indicate that Akkadian š was actually pronounced s (maybe only in Assyria)? And why was the š preserved in the name of Shalmaneser (only one of the two times)?

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Akkadian š is cognate to Hebrew š and sometimes ś but not s. The Hebrew cognate of šarru is śar. Regarding Aramaic: Interestingly enough, Aššur-banipal is attested in Aramaic as Asnappar, but the Syriac translation (not sure where it's attested) is given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashurbanipal) as ܐܫܘܪ ܒܢܐ ܐܦܠܐ, which is doubly strange since the Aramaic cognate is t and not š.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While Akkadian *š* is generally cognate with Hebrew *š* or *ś*, there's good reason to believe its pronunciation was quite different! The reason it's transcribed as *š* is mostly historical—Akkadian was first deciphered by comparison to other Semitic languages, so when a certain phoneme seemed to correspond regularly to Hebrew *š*, they named it *š*.

But there's evidence that, at least in some dialects, this *š* was pronounced as `/s/`. When the Hittites used Akkadian cuneiform to write their own language, they used the *š* signs for `/s/` and left the *s* signs unused. (We know the Hittite phoneme was pronounced `/s/`, not `/ʃ/`, because of transcriptions of Hittite names into Egyptian: *Ḫattušiliš* becomes Egyptian *xtsl*, *Muršiliš* becomes Egyptian *mrsl*, *Šuppiluliumaš* becomes Egyptian *spll*. Egyptian had both `/s/` and `/ʃ/`, so the consistent use of one transcription over the other is meaningful.)

EDIT: Further evidence comes from the tablet *Tell el Amarna 1921 1154*, which transcribes some Egyptian words in Akkadian cuneiform; Egyptian *s* is definitely rendered with Akkadian *š*, and Egyptian *š* may be rendered with Akkadian *s* (this half of the equation is less clear).

Huehnergard and Woods (in the *Cambridge Encyclopedia of the World's Ancient Languages*) explain it thus. Akkadian originally inherited four sibilants from Proto-Semitic: *š s z ṣ* `/s t͡s d͡z t͡sʼ/`. Later, *s* became a simple fricative, but this development happened separately in different dialects: *š s* `/ʃ s/` in Babylonian but *š s* `/s ʃ/` in Assyrian. Huehnergard had previously suggested that `[s]` and `[ʃ]` were realizations of a single phoneme, which would explain *Šalmanesar*, but the dialect-variation theory seems to have supplanted this.

Comment: The phonetically conditioned distribution is interesting, but phonetically conditioned where? What other loans are there like Shalmaneser that could indicate free variation? (And in both cases: theorized by whom?)

Comment: @ba Currently trying to find a non-paywalled source for the idea that it was dialect variation (taken from your comment on the other answer); Huehnergard's grammar mentions the two-realizations theory, and I'll try to find a good cite for that too.

Comment: @ba Updated with new citations. Huehnergard's more recent writings agree with the Encyclopedia of Hebrew Language and Linguistics, so I put that theory front and center.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, some people think Akkadian š was pronounced [s].

> For the sibilants, traditionally /š/ has been held to be postalveolar [ʃ], and /s/, /z/, /ṣ/ analyzed as fricatives; but attested assimilations in Akkadian suggest otherwise. For example, when the possessive suffix -šu is added to the root awat ('word'), it is written awassu ('his word')

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkadian#Consonants)

There is also relevant discussion in the Wikipedia article on Proto-Semitic:

> The "maximal affricate" position additionally posits that *s *z were actually affricates [t͡s d͡z] while *š was actually a simple fricative [s] [...] According to Kogan, the affricate interpretation of Akkadian s z ṣ is generally accepted

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Semitic_language#Fricatives)

I am not familar with any of the literature, so I can't expand beyond what Wikipedia says.

Comment: Good answer, but I still wonder why it got transliterated as š in the first place, if there might have been differences between dialects, or if it was just based on the Hebrew cognate

Comment: @ba: The Wikipedia article on PS indicates that "The notation given here is traditional and is based on their pronunciation in Hebrew, which has traditionally been extrapolated to Proto-Semitic"

Comment: I found a more detailed answer that addresses the inconsistency. "Akkadian Lownwords" [here](https://referenceworks.brillonline.com/browse/encyclopedia-of-hebrew-language-and-linguistics) (paywall): "Moreover, the consonants š and s were pronounced differently in the two principal Akk dialects, Babylonian (Bab) and Assyrian (Assyr), such that Bab š=[š], s=[s]; Assyr š=[s], s =[š], whence the BH spelling, imitating the pronunciation rather than preserving the etymology, (cont. >)

Comment: (< cont.) permits identification of the donor dialect (cf. BH שַׁלְמֹנִים šalmōnīm < Bab šulmānu ‘bribe’, BH סֶגֶן sɛḡɛn < Assyr šaknu ‘governor’)." I think you should add that detail to make your answer more complete.